# JS : callback function is called when image is loaded but in fact image.complete shows it's not loaded

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, onload

Hi everyone and Happy New Year,

I'm working on a small game project using JavaScript and I encountered a problem when loading images.
I want all the images to be loaded before I display them so I created a map in which each image is linked to `false`, and when the image is loaded, an event listener calls a function which set the image to `true` in my map.
But sometimes, my map is full of `true` without any image on my screen and when I print `img.complete` it's false, meaning it's not loaded.
Everything here is in a class of my file and `this.chargementImg` is the map.

Here is the image loading function:

```
chargerImage(chemin)
    {
        let img = new Image();
        this.chargementImg.set(chemin, false);
        img.addEventListener("load", this.updateChargementImg(chemin));
        img.src = chemin;
        return img;
    }
```

And the callback function:

```
updateChargementImg(chemin)
    {
        this.chargementImg.set(chemin, true);
    }
```

Console output when no images shown:

```
Map(3) {'./elements/images/fonds/sol/DarkSpace.png' => true,
'./elements/images/fonds/mur/Castle2.png' => true,
'./elements/images/ennemies/Earthspirit.png' => true}

img1.complete : false
img2.complete : false
img3.complete : false
```

I don't understand why it's not working.
Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `load EventListener` an unnamed function. Inside that put the `updateChargementImg` and `return img`. There will then be no race or async.

```
img.addEventListener("load", function(){
 this.updateChargementImg(chemin);
  return img;
});
img.src = chemin;
```